# Bounty for bad answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

Dear users I have recently offered a new bounty. If the answer is modest or inconsistent or insufficient what are the actions I should take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unfortunate thing about bounties are that they are irreversible. Once issued, it's an immediate withdrawal from your reputation bank. At best, the bounty adds more attention to your question by bumping it to the top of the active questions list, as well as the [featured questions tab](https://tex.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured). At worst, no additional interest is shown at the end of the bounty period, leaving you with no return on your investment. Here's an excerpt on how the bounty system works in the latter case(s):

> #### What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no
>   bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Part of what you're "paying for" with a bounty is for higher question
>   visibility and increased answerer motivation.  A bounty does **not**
>   guarantee a response and is **not refunded** if none are received.
>
> #### What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered? / What is automatic awarding?
>
> [Approximately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147577/168244)
>   24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period
>   ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the
>   bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was
>   posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full
>   bounty.
>
> Otherwise, all or half of the bounty is awarded to the highest-scored
>   answer out of those which...
>
> - ...were posted *after* the bounty was started, and
> - ...have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - ...were not written by the bounty starter.
>
> If the chosen answer was accepted by the question owner, it will
>   receive the full bounty. Otherwise, it will receive half the bounty.
>   If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is
>   chosen.
>
> If no answer meets any of the above two criteria, the bounty is not
>   awarded to any answer, and is *not* refunded to the bounty starter.

There may still be hope! Perhaps find similar questions than the one you posted a bounty for and see who wrote answers to those or commented favourably. Ping them with a comment and see if they could spend some time answering the question.

Reference: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/168244)

Comment: Finally, do the bountys have an interest?

Comment: @marmot Oh okay, the machine translator mistranslated. I meant, "Do bountys bring something?"

Comment: @AndréC I was going to say that the bounties have an interest, but their treatment is shockingly exploitative and their interest almost entirely ignored.

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of bounties is to get attention for the question - they don't guarantee to receive good answers or even any answers at all.

If you don't like the answer you get, live with it or start a new bounty after the current bounty is expired.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can start a dialogue to make the answer more substantive, consistent and coherent.